# What are Logic Pro’s moving green bars called and what are they measuring?

Tags: logic-pro

What are the moving green bars in the following picture that Logic Pro displays called?

What do they measure?

What is the smaller colored line often moving above the bar?

What is the number scale Logic uses, quadratic?

[image: Logic Mixpanel]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the moving green bars in the following picture that Logic Pro displays called?

This is called a Level Meter.

> What do they measure?

They mesure [dBFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS)

> What is the smaller colored line often moving above the bar?

This is the maximal value the audio peak reached

> What is the number scale Logic uses, quadratic?

I'm not sure to well understand the question but dBs are logarithmic. See [this link](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8785/how-to-compute-dbfs).

Comment: How does a VU meter compare to a [Peak meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_meter)?

Comment: I think calling the green bars 'vu-meter' is misleading. 'audio level meters' would be more appropriate as they don't seem to respect any standard in terms of ballistic.

Comment: It's called a 'Level Meter' in the Logic Pro X manual: https://help.apple.com/logicpro/mac/10.3/index.html#/lgcpbc219210

Comment: The scale is set in the Display preferences, and is referred to as 'Exponential' or 'Sectional dB-linear'

Comment: My bad for the vu-meter. I don't have Logic so I'll take your answer @SimonBosley if your ok with that or do another answer if you want to. Thx